# Beer color - Calculating MCU

Tags: all-grain, brewing, color

I have two questions regarding calculating the MCU for a beer receipt.

```
MCU = (weight of grain i lbs) * (color in degrees lovibond) / (volume in gallons)
```

- For my grains, I have the color listed in SRM, and not Lovibond. Do I have to first convert the color to Lovibond, and then put it into the formula, or is there a variation of this formula that I can use with SRM as well?
- Which volume do I use here? Do I use the volume at the point in the process where I want to calculate the color? Then I guess post-boil volume would be the best volume to use, or are you supposed to just use the batch size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume to use is the final volume you are aiming for in the fermenter; yes the post boil volume.

Lovibond -> SRM

°L = (SRM + 0.76) ÷ 1.3546